# How to pass access the variable of one function in another function

Tags: javascript, html

```
function var1() {
    console.log("in function one");
    var varval1 = "life";
    alert("var one value"+varval1);
    return varval1;
}

function var2() {
    console.log("in function two");
    alert("var two value"+varval1);
}

var1();
var2();
```

I want to access the value of `varval1` inside `var2()`. However, it gives an error saying the value is not defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function var1(){
    console.log("in function one");
    var varval1 = "life";
    alert("var one value"+varval1);
    return varval1;
}

function var2( varval1 ){
    console.log("in function two");
    alert("var two value"+varval1);
}

var2(var1());
```

Answer (score 2):

`varval1` is defined in the scope of the function `var1` but not in `var2`'s scope. So, it won't be available to the code outside `var1`. However, all the functions defined inside `var1` will have access to the variables defined inside it.

You have several options here.

1. Define function `var2` inside `var1`. (but then, you won't be able to call `var2` easily using `var2()`)
2. Declare `varval1` as a global variable. (By removing var in front of it. But, this is generally a bad idea)
   3)
3. Return the value of `varval1` from function `var1` and store it in a variable `val2` can access.

Also, try to name your variables and functions meaningfully.

Scope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line where `varval1` is defined will do it:

```
function var1() {
    console.log("in function one");
    varval1 = "life";
    alert("var one value"+varval1);
    return varval1;
```

}

This is also equivalent to writing

```
window.varval1 = "life";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `var2()` to

```
function var2(){
console.log("in function two");
varval1=var1();
alert("var two value"+varval1);
}
```